# VS2017 performance profiling only shows function pointers in dotnet core app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a dotnet core project that runs via Kestrel.

I have published it and generated both the exe that hosts the dll, and of course, the dll.

When I use the Performance Profiler in VS2017, I set it to use instrumentation, I ensured that the csproj file properties are set up to create a 'full' pdb (though I'm starting to doubt that does anything that matters in dotnet core, but the output pdb file is bigger than when it was set to portable).

When all is said and done, I end up with a profiler output that looks like the linked image.

Is there any way with current tooling (5/4/2017) to actually get a useful profiler output?

[Profiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnzrF.png)

Comment: Did you read [this](https://dustinewers.com/profiling-on-net-core/) article?

Comment: Only after you linked it. As it happens, I found out that if I add Application Insights to my project and then enable CPU profiling, it works great. Thank you so much!